# Python flask render template during loading

Tags: python, multithreading, flask

I have a function that calls an Api during loading and I'm wondering if there is any good solution to change the render template. I found a few examples of the same problem, but the all are looking very difficult and messy. Here is my code so far:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template, request, redirect, url_for
import time
import threading



app = Flask(__name__)

cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/*": {"origins": "*"}})

def thread_function(name):
    print("Thread %s: starting", name)
    time.sleep(2)
    print("Finish")


@app.route("/load")
def load():
    x = threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(1,))
    x.daemon = True
    x.start()
    while (x.is_alive()):
        render_template('loading.html')

    print("X is dead")
    return render_template('allRight.html')
``
```